# Arrays with rigid variable

Tags: arrays, haskell

Well, I was doing a problem in which function I was using had a rigid variable. I had an idea of using arrays for that problem. So I thought of using arrays with same rigid variable as of the function I was creating, but I have no idea how to make an array with a rigid variable.
I tried the following thing but with no effect:

```
rearrange ::  [Int] -> [a] -> [a]

rearrange l la = elems (f 1 posarr)    
  where
    b = length l
    listarr :: Array Int Int
    listarr = listArray (1,b) l
    arra :: Array Int  c
    arra = listArray (1,b) la
    posarr :: Array Int  c
    posarr = listArray (1,b) la
    f i posarr
      | (b < i) = posarr
      | otherwise = f (i+1) (posarr // [(listarr!i,arra!i)] )
```

The error I am getting is of rigid variable.
What is the possible fix for that? Please give the idea of how to make arrays with rigid variables like a in the following function I have used

Answer (score 5):

You're having trouble because the "inner" type signatures you've written out don't mean quite what they look like they'd mean. In particular, your uses of `c` do not correspond with one another not the `a` in the top signature and they must. Haskell is complaining that these "rigidly defined" type variables, despite being variables, cannot be the same, but since they're based on a "rigid" choice of what `a` is... they must!

You can make GHC (but not Haskell in general) behave the way you'd like with an extension called `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` where your code becomes

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

rearrange :: forall a . [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
rearrange l la = elems (f 1 posarr)
  where
    b = length l
    listarr :: Array Int Int
    listarr = listArray (1, b) l
    arra :: Array Int a
    arra = listArray (1,b) la
    posarr :: Array Int a
    posarr listArray (1,b) la
    f i posarr
      | (b < i) = posarr
      | otherwise = f (i+1) (posarr // [(listarr!i,arra!i)])
```

Note that all I did was add the explicit `forall` and changed some `c` variables to `a`. What `ScopedTypeVariables` let you do is introduce type variable scopes using `forall` where any type signatures in code that is indented below such an explicitly `forall`'d signature can re-use the type variable names introduced in that `forall` and have them correspond exactly.

Which might make more sense under examining how Haskell interprets type signatures without the extension. In particular, there is an implicit `forall` before *every* type signature

```
                                  -- is actually
foo :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]          foo :: forall a. [a] -> [a] -> [a]
foo xs ys = it where              foo xs ys = it where
  it :: [a]                         it :: forall a. [a]
  it = xs ++ ys                     it = xs ++ ys
```

Which forces the `a` variable in each of these type signatures to be different and thus this fragment of code cannot compile because it is only valid if those two `a`s are the same. With `ScopedTypeVariables` we have

```
foo :: forall a . [a] -> [a] -> [a]
foo xs ys = it where
  it :: [a]
  it = xs ++ ys
```

where the inner signature's `a` is scoped to mean exactly the same `a` as in outer signature's.

Comment: Is the following code compiling without error. i did the same thing as you mentioned but it is saying something  like this: Illegal symbol '.' in type  Perhaps you intended -XRanktype or similar flag to enable explicit forall........ But one thing I'm  using Ubuntu and compiling using terminal, so does it produce some error.

Comment: You must use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to enable `forall`s. `RankNTypes` is a completely different extension. Both of them depend upon and automatically flag the `ExplicitForalls` extension, which you can choose separately as well if you like though it has no semantic advantage by itself.

Comment: If you're using GHCi you can set these flags on the fly like `:set -XScopedTypeVariables`

Comment: And yes, I just checked my `foo` example and it compiles cleanly with those flags.

Comment: Will you please tell me how and where to write what for setting that flag?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. You can do it on a per-file basis by placing the line `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

J. Abrahamson explained how to fix the errors at hand, but note that this is way overcomplicated. You can just omit all the local type signatures<sup>1</sup>, the compiler is able to infer those by itself. (There sure enough *are* applications where you need local type signatures, or where it's helpful for readability; then you often need `ScopedTypeVariables`. But not for such a simple function, IMO.)

Speaking of unnecessary complexity — there is no benefit whatsoever in explicitly index-iterating through an array you've just created with `listArray`: it's pretty much equivalent (but much unwieldier) to just recursively destructing the list. And that can be written as a fold. Or, in cases like this where you iterate through two lists "in parallel", to folding on the `zip` of those lists. In fact you don't need even the fold: there's a good reason that `(//)` accepts a *list* of index-value pairs rather than just a single pair – because you'll normally want to update multiple elements<sup>2</sup> in batch.

That simplifies your function drastically:

```
rearrange l la = elems $ posarr // zip l la
  where posarr = listArray (1, length l) la
```

---

<sup>1</sup>So I'm not misunderstood: I really mean only *local* type signatures. On the top-level, everything should have a signature except perhaps completely trivial stuff that's only used inside your module (but then it's in a way also a local signature).

<sup>2</sup>There is more to this than just convenience: your solution is actually *very inefficient*, because at each modification step a copy of the entire array needs to be made, so you can safely access the intermediate results in the purely functional language. Calling `//` with multiple pairs right away omits this: since the intermediate steps are never exposed, GHC can do magic under the hood, do *destructive updates* like you could in an imperative language (or in Haskell with the `ST` monad). Which is much faster.

Comment: For the record, this is a much better suggestion than mine to improve the overall code quality.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you tell me that for each update in array, it takes complexity order of size n of the length of the list? Thus        for n updation it takes order of $n^2$ steps.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the problem with your approach. For each _seperate update_; as I said `//` batches them to avoid this trouble.