# Trouble explicitly specifying a type using a type variable

Tags: haskell

The following is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do...

```
test :: Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
test (Just x) = x
test Nothing  = (maxBound :: a)
```

The `maxBound` function is polymorphic - one of the methods of the `Bounded` typeclass. Because of that, when I use it I need to specify which version of `Bounded` I want. **In this simplified example, that type could be inferred from the context - but in the real problem it can't** - the explicit type is necessary in the real problem, though not really here.

My function is polymorphic too. I can't specify a concrete type directly, only a type variable. The appropriate type variable is `a`, for which I have specified the `Bounded a` constraint.

Compiling this, I get the following error...

```
temp.hs:4:18:
    Could not deduce (Bounded a1) arising from a use of `maxBound'
    from the context (Bounded a)
      bound by the type signature for test :: Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
      at temp.hs:2:9-33
    Possible fix:
      add (Bounded a1) to the context of
        an expression type signature: a1
        or the type signature for test :: Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
    In the expression: (maxBound :: a)
    In an equation for `test': test Nothing = (maxBound :: a)
```

As far as I can tell, this means that the `a` in `maxBound :: a` was considered separate from the `a` that I intended (the type variable in the signature for the function). `a1` is the new name that GHC invented to disambiguate the two `a` variables which it considers separate. GHC considers the `a` in `maxBound :: a` to indicate that it can use any type here (!) and therefore complains because "any type" isn't restrictive enough.

This is using GHC version 7.6.3 as supplied in the (I think) most recent Haskell Platform.

I've had similar issues before, but always mixed with other issues, so the problem went away once I fixed those other problems. I dismissed it as being caused by the other issues and forgot about it. No such luxury here - that minimal example above isn't the real problem, but it depends on a solution to the exact same problem.

So... why is GHC treating the `a` in `maxBound :: a` as independent of the type variable `a` for the whole function? And how do I fix this to select the correct version of `maxBound`?

Comment: Have a look at [the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables), it quite instantly solves your problem. Incidentally, just today there was [another question with that same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876433/arrays-with-rigid-variable/19879861#19879861), with a nice explanation about the explicit forall in the answers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - thanks, at first sight that looks like the answer.

Comment: @leftroundabout - that's definitely the answer - could you please post it *as* an answer so I can accept it? Adding a link to the [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) page on the issue could be useful too.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler solution is just to elide the type annotation on `maxBound`. `test Nothing = maxBound` works just fine, as the inferencer is able to deduce which instance of `maxBound` to use, unless you really want to have the type annotation for some reason.

Comment: @sabauma - as I said in the question, "**In this simplified example, that type could be inferred from the context - but in the real problem it can't** - the explicit type is necessary in the real problem, though not really here." In the real problem, that simply wouldn't work - specifically, I have `fromEnum (maxBound :: a)` and of course `fromEnum` is polymorphic in its argument type, so type inference cannot determine the type of `maxBound` from that. Explicitly stating which `fromEnum` to use (rather than `maxBound`) leads to the same problem - either way needs scoped type variables.

Comment: Depending on your problem, you might also be able to use the standard Haskell `asTypeOf` function, which was used for this purpose before ghc got the ScopedTypeVariables extension.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen - interesting, but sadly it doesn't work for me. One thing the real problem does that's the same as the `test` above is take a `Maybe` type for the argument, and the problem arises in the `Nothing` case where there's no value to evaluate the type of. I had thought of trying `if True then maxBound else x` to give type inference a hint, but there was nothing to use for the `x` (and even if it had worked, it's ugly).

Comment: On the "This question may already have an answer here:" - I believe it's correct, the **answer** is there - but I'm not sure the question is a duplicate. In particular, if I read that question before asking this one, I don't think I'd have realized it was related to the same issue I was having unless I read the answers as well.

Comment: Pretty ugly and useless by now, but just to prove that it *can* be done with asTypeOf: `test (y@Nothing) = asTypeOf maxBound x where Just x = y` Laziness means the Just pattern will never be tried so it doesn't matter that it's a lie, it still can guide the types.

Comment: @Steve314 Are you using `fromEnum` in both branches? If so, perhaps you can move it outside the branch; e.g. `fromEnum . fromMaybe maxBound`.

Comment: @Daniel - the reason for the simplified example is because the real problem is more complicated. Using `fromEnum` and `maxBound` is just part of the how. The real problem is trying out an idea where there's a separate type for a single "bound" value (boundary between adjacent values in an `Ix` type), to see if using a separate type (with one extra value - hence `Maybe`) rather than conventions like inclusive or half-open makes binary search and similar algorithms cleaner. It won't be efficient, but I don't really care about that.

Comment: @Daniel - The main problem now is all the underflow and overflow checks needed primarily so the new `Bound a` type can implement the `Enum`, `Bounded` etc interfaces correctly, especially given the fact that `fromEnum` and `toEnum` always work with `Int` which is signed, doesn't do overflow/underflow checks on basic arithmetic, isn't necessarily 2s complement etc. It's awkward to bounds-check offsetting an enum by an `Int` when you can't necessarily represent the distance to `maxBound` or `minBound` in `Int` (e.g. `maxBound - (-1) > maxBound` and can't make overflow-behavior assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem is in fact, that GHC tried to see function as

```
test :: forall a. Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
test (Just x) = x
test Nothing  = (maxBound :: forall a. a)
```

You need ScopedTypeVariables extension and rewrite function to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

test :: forall a. Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
test (Just x) = x
test Nothing  = (maxBound :: a)
```

Now we see, that inner `a` is depend on outer `a`

**UPDATE**

If you already wrote the signatiure, you don't need any extension.

Next function works fine!

```
test :: Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
test (Just x) = x
test Nothing  = maxBound
```